# CXF, WS-Security and Spring : UserToken

Tags: java, spring, cxf, ws-security

My websrervice works using authentication, but the problem is that it's static, it's written in the XML file, and even in the class that implements CallbackHandler.
I want to execute my webservice but by using a login and a password that user will enter in a console

This is the client part where I wrote the user :

```
<bean id="wss4jOutInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor">
    <property name="properties">
        <map>
            <entry key="action" value="UsernameToken Timestamp" />
            **<entry key="user" value="pT64f349"/>**
            <entry key="passwordType" value="PasswordDigest" />
            <entry>
                <key>
                    <value>passwordCallbackRef</value>
                </key>
                <ref bean="passwordCallback" />
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And this is where I put my password :

```
public class ClientPasswordCallback implements CallbackHandler{

@Override
public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {
    WSPasswordCallback callback = (WSPasswordCallback) callbacks[0];
    if(callback.getIdentifier().equals("pT64f349")){
        **callback.setPassword("pass");**
    }
}
```

}

Thnx a lot

Comment: What do you mean by "entering a console?"

Comment: @reef : like if I execute my jar : 

java -jar myapplication.jar userName password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe adapt your `ClientPasswordCallback` to read the user inputs from a `ThreadLocal` (see [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) and [example 1](http://javaboutique.internet.com/tutorials/localdata/) or [example 2](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_concurrency_thread_local.shtml)).

You'll have first to fill the inputs into the `ThreadLocal` and then you can read them in the `ClientPasswordCallback`.

Comment: I'll try it and tell you, thnx a lot

Comment: @reef : I did it, and can fill my ClientPasswordCallback with the appropriate data from the ThreadLocal. The big problem now is to set the <entry key="user" value="pT64f349"/> value from the ThreadLocal. Any solution ?

Comment: Maybe you can combine your ThreadLocal solution a non-Spring configuration of your Wss4j-interceptor. Take a look at the CXF website for how to configure your interceptor programmatically (see http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html). Configuring your interceptors programmatically allows you to have dynamic values instead of fixed ones as in your actual Xml configuration file.

Comment: It works, I added : 
   WSS4JOutInterceptor interceptor = (WSS4JOutInterceptor) applicationContext.getBean("wss4jOutInterceptor");
   interceptor.setProperty("user", "pT64f349");
Thnx a lot :)

Comment: Great ;) Combining the two solutions will give you a way to add your user credentials dynamically. Glad it helped!

Comment: :) Now I learned something new :) ThreadLocal and passing parameters to a bean in xml using spring ^^ Cheers !

Comment: An other solution without use a ThreadLocal : 
when I get my bean using spring, I put the login and password using a setter in it :)

Comment: Indeed. I would recommend the programmatically-based solution so that you're sure of the bean content.

Comment: After you set the property using 
interceptor.setProperty("user", "pT64f349");

How do you access that property from within your ClientPasswordCallback?

Comment: The idea is to combine both your interceptor and a ThreadLocal that will make the link between the interceptor and the callback. Take a closer look to the original response.